# Android emulator on Apple Silicon M1 does not start in 2022

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I have the latest Android Studio Arctic Fox.
I have created a virtual device using

- AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device
- select Pixel 4
- select API 25, ABI arm64-v8a
- start the device from AVD play button

The device starts and begins booting but its gets stuck in the process:

[image: Stuck device]

I tried different device api combinations, same result.

**What can I do to run an Android Emulator on an Apple computer with M1 chip?**

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the combination "Nexus 5 / API 29" works fine.
Maybe it is related to the fact that Google Play is supported for this combination:

[image: Devices]